# Why is deleting files in Ubuntu slow?

Tags: linux, command-line, rm

I read on a stackoveflow post that on Linux, when we delete a file, it is not actually deleted, only the link from the inode table is removed to that file. If that is the case, then why isn't delete a constant time operation?

I also tried an experiment:
I created a folder with 1500 images and created a tar object of these images. Both the directory and tar file are of same size. Timings for deleting the tar object and the directory of 1500 images are as follows

Deleting tar file `time rm test.tar`:

```
real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.024s
```

Deleting directory: `time rm -r test`

```
real    0m0.219s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.191s
```

As per my understanding, this difference in time is because of
unlinking 1 file vs unlinking 1500 files. But shouldn't the tar object deletion be 1500x faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's **not** a simple "mark a single inode deleted" operation: https://www.slashroot.in/how-does-file-deletion-work-linux

At least on ext4 file deletion is a whole lot faster than on ext2/ext3 partitions due to the use of extents.

In case of SSDs file deletion could be slower than necessary due to the use of the "discard" option which tells your SSD to physically discard all the blocks belonging to a file in order to extend your SSD lifespan. It's highly **not** advisable to disable it.